# Application crashed with signal SIGILL

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

Hi I am facing a lot of crashes in my Application. Here is crash logs:

```
Thread 1 (main):
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run( ZygoteInit.java:827)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
at **ak.hide.android.loveuu.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:134)**
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> I searched over the internet but i didn't find any library/link where i can find this class: `ak.hide.android.loveuu.XposedBridge.main->XposedBridge.java`
>   Yes i can see other libraries but not exact one.

Comment: It's seems you have installed an unofficial Xposed Framework or a bugged Xposed Module that interfere with normal App esecution. Please check to have installed an official and compatible Xposed Framework for your Android version (based on SDK if I remember well). If you never installed Xposed, than you have a "virus" that has installed it to have access to all opened Apps.

Comment: @emandt actually we publish App on play store and peoples are facing this issue. i's wondering, customer facing this issue all have virus or that bad Xposed framework ?

Comment: Loadng XposedBridge BEFORE the Zygote means that users are using Xposed Framework. So I think those users have Xposed Installed on a Rooted phone. However that PackageName is not the official one, so or many people has flashed/installed a wrong/Unofficial Xposed Framework (very dangerous thing!) or they have a virus that have installed it for App monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

looks like someone has rooted a phone and installed xposedbridge to either swap your resources or run commands before and after a method call of your package.  I don't see what you can do about it ? its accompanying zygote (the first process) in android.  someone with a rooted device can do whatever they please.